# packing a c++ project for release with some dependencies like pthread boost curl etc

Tags: c++

I am writing an c++ application where i use a lot of libraries like boost curl,pthread etc. I am not sure how to pack the application with all the dependencies for production use.
What is the best way to distribute the application with dependencies?

Comment: Why would you want to do it? Just provide ./configure && make && make install.

Comment: 'cause, you know, thats how my grandmother installs software on her laptop =P

Comment: I believe it's a valid & good question. Especially since the necessary steps probably differ quite a lot depending on the platform.

Comment: Look at the platform(s) for which you want to make it available.  For example each linux distribution has its own method (e.g. debian, gentoo, etc.) and for Mac OS X macports, homebrew, etc. all have their own specifications for applications.  Even if you have no intention of using such a method, you can get ideas.  Otherwise, you can package everything up and create an installer (e.g. Mac OS X dmg or windows self extracting exe).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the platform you plan to use.
If you use pthread you are probably targeting POSIX systems. If you are planning to use Debian you can package everything in a Deb package and configure the package to handle the dependency. The same goes for the RPMs of redhat systems.
I'm not experienced about the best way to address an OSX system